# Can I preg_match two things (One OR another)

Tags: preg-match

```
preg_match('/src="([^"]+)"/', $content, $matches);
```

So what if I first want to look for src and second for url?

That's simple question, nothing else to explain really.

Answer (score 0):

Just add another match group to your regex by putting parens around src:

```
preg_match('/(src)="([^"]+)"/', $content, $matches);
```

Everything enclosed in params matches as its own match group so: ( also the i at the end makes it case insensetive)

```
/(src)="([^"]+)"/i
```

Compared against:

```
src="http://www.test.com/"
```

should return the following match groups:

```
1.  src
2.  http://www.test.com/
```

I hope I understood the question correctly.